# Langton's Ant simulation

Tags: c#, time-limit-exceeded, simulation

I created a simple program to simulate the Ant's path.  The Ant moves north, west, east and south. Each time the Anth moves to an "uncharted" location, I build a Square and give it a color. Each time the Ant steps in a square, the square changes color and the Ant rotates 90° and keeps her track. I use a `Stack` where I push my `Squares`. The `steps` list is something I need to keep track of [the path of the Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant). I need to find when the Path stabilizes (Roughly after 10000 steps) and the Ant moves in a uniform manner.

It works great until 10<sup>6</sup> (takes 5 minutes to run). After that it takes more than 14 hours to get to the 10<sup>7</sup> mark. I don't get why it takes so much more time, shouldn't it just take **10 × time it took to get to 10<sup>6</sup> iterations** assuming my algorithm is **o(n)**?

I would like to keep the approach single threaded.  What can I optimize?

---

```
enum Orientation{
  NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST
}
```

---

```
public class Square { 
        public int x, y;
        // White = 0, Black = 1
        public int color = 0;
}
```

---

```
int color = 0;
int x = 0, y = 1;
Stack<Square> squares = new Stack<Square>();
Orientation orientation = Orientation.NORTH;
List<Orientation> steps = new List<Orientation>();
for (int i = 0, counter = 0; i < 10000000; ++i, ++counter)
{

    // First
    if(i == 0)
    {
        squares.Push(new Square() { x = 0, y = 1, color = 1 });
        // Rotate
        orientation = Rotate(orientation, color == 0 ? true : false);
        steps.Add(orientation);
        continue;
    }
    // Move step
    if (orientation == Orientation.NORTH) y += 1;
    if (orientation == Orientation.EAST) x -= 1;
    if (orientation == Orientation.WEST) x += 1;
    if (orientation == Orientation.SOUTH) y -= 1;

    // Check what the step has
    Square s = squares.Where(square => square.x == x && square.y == y).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault();

    // if null create one and rotate
    if (s == null)
    {
        squares.Push(CreateSquare(x, y, 1));
        orientation = Rotate(orientation, true);
        steps.Add(orientation);
    }else if(s.color == 1)
    {
        s.color = 0;
        orientation = Rotate(orientation, false);
        steps.Add(orientation);
    }else
    {
        s.color = 1;
        orientation = Rotate(orientation, true);
        steps.Add(orientation);
    }

    // 10^6 mark
    if (i == 999999)
    {
            blackSquaresAt100k = squares.Where(sqa => sqa.color == 1).Count();
            Console.WriteLine(blackSquaresAt100k);
    }

    // 10^7 mark
    if (i == 9999999)
    {
        blackSquaresAt1M = squares.Where(sqa => sqa.color == 1).Count();
        int totalNrOfBlackSquares = (blackSquaresAt1M - blackSquaresAt100k) * 12 + blackSquaresAt1M;
        Console.WriteLine(totalNrOfBlackSquares);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is on the verge of being closed for _Lack of concrete context_ reason. At least, what is `squares`? Please add _all_ necessary details.

Comment: @vnp Let me know if you need anything more

Comment: Well now we see that since `squares` is a `Stack`, and `Stack.Where` takes linear time, the entire thing cannot be \$O(n)\$. Use `Set`.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete; for example, the `Orientation` enum is never defined, and the `color` variable referenced in the `if(i==0)` block isn't declared. But as @vnp pointed out, your main performance problem is almost certainly the `.Where`, which may iterate the entire collection. Switching to a `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Square>`, and using `TryGetValue` will help you a lot. You may still have issues related to memory allocation as the collections grow very large, however.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestion I shall try it

Comment: @benj2240 It doesnt grow that large, after 14hours running it was still at 120Mb

Comment: @benj2240 Now it runs less than 30 seconds. Wow, major flaw in my code

Comment: Based on your last two comments (I mean no insult to you)... But it reminded me of the scene in The Lord of the Rings, where it takes hours for the trees to say "Hello" to one another. Whereas in English it is accomplished in seconds. --- You managed to create the tree language!

Comment: @Svek Haha, would never be insulted by one of my fav movies of all time

Answer (score 2):

### Optimisation

> I use a `Stack` where I push my `Squares`.

A stack is the correct data structure when you want last-in-first-out behaviour. Is that the behaviour you need here?

> It works great until 10<sup>6</sup> (takes 5 minutes to run).

That is a long way from "*great*". 10<sup>6</sup> shouldn't take 10 seconds. Use the right data structure for the task, which here is something with amortised constant time insertion and lookup.

### Other notes

> ```
> public class Square { 
>         public int x, y;
>         // White = 0, Black = 1
>         public int color = 0;
> }
> ```

Why are all of the fields mutable? Why is there no explicit constructor? Rather than using a 32-bit type to store a single bit and needing to document the legal values, why not use a 1-bit type (i.e. `bool isBlack`)?

---

> ```
> int color = 0;
> ```

Does this need such a wide scope?

---

> ```
> for (int i = 0, counter = 0; i < 10000000; ++i, ++counter)
> ```

What is the purpose of `counter`? As far as I can tell, it isn't used anywhere.

---

> ```
>         squares.Push(new Square() { x = 0, y = 1, color = 1 });
> ```

...

> ```
>         squares.Push(CreateSquare(x, y, 1));
> ```

Why the discrepancy?

---

> ```
>         orientation = Rotate(orientation, color == 0 ? true : false);
> ```

`condition ? true : false` is an unnecessarily long way of writing `condition`.

---

> ```
>     if (orientation == Orientation.NORTH) y += 1;
>     if (orientation == Orientation.EAST) x -= 1;
>     if (orientation == Orientation.WEST) x += 1;
>     if (orientation == Orientation.SOUTH) y -= 1;
> ```

This is precisely the kind of thing that `switch` statements were invented to handle.

---

> ```
>     // if null create one and rotate
>     if (s == null)
>     {
>         squares.Push(CreateSquare(x, y, 1));
>         orientation = Rotate(orientation, true);
>         steps.Add(orientation);
>     }else if(s.color == 1)
>     {
>         s.color = 0;
>         orientation = Rotate(orientation, false);
>         steps.Add(orientation);
>     }else
>     {
>         s.color = 1;
>         orientation = Rotate(orientation, true);
>         steps.Add(orientation);
>     }
> ```

Don't repeat yourself. This could be refactored as

```
    if (s == null)
    {
        s = new Square { x = x, y = y, color = 0 };
        squares.Push(s);
    }

    orientation = Rotate(orientation, s.color == 0);
    steps.Add(orientation);
    s.color = 1 - s.color;
```

---

> ```
>             blackSquaresAt100k = squares.Where(sqa => sqa.color == 1).Count();
> ```

`Count` has an overload which takes a condition, so `enumerable.Where(foo).Count()` can be refactored to `enumerable.Count(foo)`.